# How to cut a SHP based on another SHP using R

Tags: shapefile, r, clip

I have a Shapefile of points with certain information. I have another Shapefile with polygons corresponding to the states of the country I am working with (in this case Mexico). Since I only want to work specifically with 3 states, I wanted to know if there is a way to get rid of the points that dont fall into these 3 states.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this type of spatial overlay using the "over" function in the sp library. This library is automatically loaded with libraries like maptools, rgdal, raster and spdep. This is because it defines the primary spatial object classes in R. If you are performing spatial analysis in R, this is a very good library to become familiar with. Almost all the spatial libraries, excepting spatstat, in R use the object classes defined by sp. For more complex geometry operations there is the rgeos library that is a port to the GEOS JTS Topology Suite. This library allows operations like buffering, union and intersect. Here is the example from the over help for what you after.

```
require(sp)

r1 = cbind(c(180114, 180553, 181127, 181477, 181294, 181007, 180409, 
180162, 180114), c(332349, 332057, 332342, 333250, 333558, 333676, 
332618, 332413, 332349))

r2 = cbind(c(180042, 180545, 180553, 180314, 179955, 179142, 179437, 
179524, 179979, 180042), c(332373, 332026, 331426, 330889, 330683, 
331133, 331623, 332152, 332357, 332373))

r3 = cbind(c(179110, 179907, 180433, 180712, 180752, 180329, 179875, 
179668, 179572, 179269, 178879, 178600, 178544, 179046, 179110),
c(331086, 330620, 330494, 330265, 330075, 330233, 330336, 330004, 
329783, 329665, 329720, 329933, 330478, 331062, 331086))

r4 = cbind(c(180304, 180403,179632,179420,180304),
c(332791, 333204, 333635, 333058, 332791))

sr1=Polygons(list(Polygon(r1)),"r1")
sr2=Polygons(list(Polygon(r2)),"r2")
sr3=Polygons(list(Polygon(r3)),"r3")
sr4=Polygons(list(Polygon(r4)),"r4")
sr=SpatialPolygons(list(sr1,sr2,sr3,sr4))
srdf=SpatialPolygonsDataFrame(sr, data.frame(cbind(1:4,5:2), row.names=c("r1","r2","r3","r4")))

data(meuse)
coordinates(meuse) = ~x+y

plot(meuse)
polygon(r1)
polygon(r2)
polygon(r3)
polygon(r4)
# retrieve mean heavy metal concentrations per polygon:
over(sr, meuse[,1:4], fn = mean)
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to crop anything.

- First make a subset containing your 3 state polygons (if you haven't done already or if there are more than 3 states)
- Then select all points that fall within those polygons (Query by location plugin in QGis. Make a new selection containing all points that are within your polygons).
- Rightclick on your point layer (points still selected) and execute the function "Save selection as", which will just save your selected points somewhere.

Comment: This is not bad at all. Thank you. But I wanted a way to do it directly in R. Is this too cumbersome?

Comment: This is of course possible but why did you then tag your question with QGis ? I don't have time to write your code, but have a look at the package sp and the functions *over* and *subset*. Manual pages should provide you with everything you need

Comment: Wow, that actually is kind of strange. I don't know why I did that. Thank you, I'll look into the Manual pages!